# TexStudio works only as root in ArchLinux

Tags: texstudio

I have installed texstudio using pacman in Arco Linux with i3wm

`sudo pacman -S texstudio`

Later when I try to open it from rofi it didn't start, so I tried opening it from terminal and I got the following output:

```
➜  ~ texstudio
Failed to create wl_display (No such file or directory)
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: offscreen, wayland-egl, xcb, eglfs, vnc, minimal, minimalegl, linuxfb, wayland, vkkhrdisplay.

[1]    89919 IOT instruction (core dumped)  texstudio
```

But when I do `sudo texstudio`
it works normally

```
➜  ~ sudo texstudio
QApplication: invalid style override 'kvantum' passed, ignoring it.
    Available styles: Windows, Fusion
qt.xkb.compose: failed to create compose table
```

Where did I go wrong?

I am trying to run texstudio in ArcoLinux, and it runs only as root user not as normal user.